# Java streams forming a map issue

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working on a framework where we are trying to convert our traditional loops to streams. My problem is I wrote two separate logics to get price and colors but I would like to merge both together so it will be presentable

Code to get the price values

```
List<Double> productPrices = product.getUpcs()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getUpcDetails().getPrice().getRetail().getPriceValue())
            .distinct()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Code to get the colors under prices

```
      product.getUpcs()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getUpcDetails().getPrice().getRetail().getPriceValue() == 74.5)
            .flatMap(e -> e.getUpcDetails().getAttributes().stream())
            .filter(e2 -> e2.getName().contentEquals("COLOR"))
            .forEach(e3 -> System.out.println(e3.getValues().get(0).get("value")));
```

I harcoded price in the above section to obtain the colors, instead, i would like to get that as input from the list of price values and get an output in

```
Map<Double,List<colors>
output Map<75.4, {blue,black,orange}>
```

I tried merging these both without success, any help would be appriciated.

Comment: looks like some sort of `groupingBy` that you need... since you need a `Map` as a result

Comment: As a side note, *never* use `double` to express money values. You’ll find loads of articles on the net about it…

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you examine [this or similar tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/) to get a bit of understanding how this works.

The key to the solution is to learn about `Collectors.groupingBy()` functionality. As a side note, there it also shows a better way of handling pricing information in Java.

But what you would need to do is something like this:

```
 Map<Double, Set<String>> productPrices = product
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getUpcDetails())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Details::getPrice,
                    Collectors.mapping(Details::getColors, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toList(),
                            (set) -> set
                                    .stream()
                                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())))

            ));
```

Since your question is a bit unclear about the details of classes involved, I assumed this simple class structure:

```
class Details {
    private double price;
    private List<String> colors;

    double getPrice() { return price; }
    List<String> getColors() { return colors; }
}

class Product {
    private Details details;

    Details getUpcDetails() { return details; }
}
```

```

It would be possible to optimize the code above but I specifically left the possibility to filter and map colours in the mapping collector.

Answer (score 1):

You can first turn your second stream into a method that gets a `List` of products (assumed to be filtered/grouped by price) and transforms it to a `List` of colors:

```
List<Color> productsToColors(final List<Product> products) {
    return products.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getUpcDetails().getAttributes().stream())
        .filter(e2 -> e2.getName().contentEquals("COLOR"))
        .map(e3 -> e3.getValues().get(0).get("value"))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

You can use the [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector to gather all products by their price in a `List` and then with a second create a second stream and the `productsToColors` method get the map you want:

```
Map<Double, List<Color>> colors = product.getUpcs().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getUpcDetails().getPrice().getRetail().getPriceValue())
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> productsToColors(e.getValue())));
```

You can also have `groupingBy` create a `TreeMap` instead so that the colors  map will be sorted by price.

As a side-note beware of comparing double values for equality like this. You may want to round them first. Or use long variables multiplied by 100 (i.e. cents).